# CodeMirror Autocomplete if token includes dot

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, codemirror

I'm using codemirror as code editor in ASP.NET application, the issue I faced is with Autocomplete if the token includes dot ".", then the highlighting breaks.

How can I have dot "." as part of the tokens?

I want it to be same as programming editors.